# downloading parts of a html page on an event

Tags: html, windows, windows-10-mobile

I am developing an universal windows app. I need to download a webpage and extract images from it.

I got the html code and extracted the links to images and downloaded them. The thing is, the site has infinite scrolling (like facebook). When I scroll down to the bottom it loads more images. I am not able to incorporate this into my app. I am a beginner and have very little knowledge of web development or windows app development. This is my first app. I am stuck and have no idea how to proceed. I don't want to use webview as it displays ads from the site and other unnecessary contents. I only want the links to those images. Please help me go past this situation. I need a way to download the new html content that the site loads when user gets to the bottom or some other way to get the image links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up about AJAX. Perhaps also JQuery

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please vist the [help] to see what and how to ask. This will likely be closed as off topic/too broad

Comment: PS: Look up "Lazy Load" - if you are trying to leech a site that does this, you may want to ask them for permission to access their API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may or may not be a me to implement this specifically because of the reason you stated. You need to determine how the site loads this information. First I would download Fiddler and in turn enable https connect logging so you can see your encrypted traffic going through Fiddler. Btw the Web View has events you can hook  to see loading URLs, etc and it can also be hidden.

So again you need to first understand how the site you want to do this on works and emulate that, assuming they don't have an api already to give you this information as mentioned I'm the comments.

When you do that, come back with code examples and you'll get better help.